# Asp.Net MVC: How to make validation messages be more nice-looking by default in case of invalid convertion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following model class:

```
public class Person{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And have following controller to edit it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPerson(Person person)
    {
        //... bla bla bla

        return View(person);
    }
}
```

the EditPerson is invoked when a form is submitted. The form contains an input named "Age". If user enters a non-numeric string - when the EditPerson is invoked, the ModelState["Info"] contains an error with text like "The value '0dfrg' is not valid for Age"

I looked into MS sources and found out that such error message is set if any type convertion fails.
But I would like to write something like "Field 'Age' must contain a number" in the described case. Is there a way to make MVC act this way if it can't convert a string to integer? (And also provide same nice error messages for other types, say, date)

**Upd:** I wanted to find a way to be able to have nice **default** error messages in case of the convertion error, so that not to worry about every particular property  (the title of this question is changed too)

Answer (score 3):

You can use validation attribute and put it for field of model like this

```
public class Person{
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Field 'Age' must contain a number")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

It's better than just perform validation only in action, in this case also client-side validation will be added.

Make sure you use html helper in your view for displaying validation. In this case simmilar to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model  => model .Age)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/j3opUQ

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I see the same "The value '0sdf' is not valid for Age." message

Comment: I updated my answer and add link to example. It did not work with Range attribute, since there data-val-number attribute is rendered for input element anyway, but with RegularExpression it works fine.

Comment: no, doesn't work for me also :( the helper I use is
`@Html.EditorFor(x=>x)`
where the model is 
`@model forms.Model.Person`

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d+", ErrorMessage = "Field 'Age' must contain a number")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solutions, but what I want is make the correct behaviour for every int, datetime etc. field that a model can contain. So that I wouldn't need to bother about such things.
I found a solution (thanks to possibility to debug MS code). It's pretty ugly, but works:

1) in Application_Start insert line:

ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new ExtendedModelBinder();

2) define ExtendedModelBinder class:

```
public class ExtendedModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        string GetErrorMessageForType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == typeof(int))
                return "You must enter an integer numeric value";
            if (type == typeof(double))
                return "You must enter a numeric value";
            return "The entered value is incorrect";
        }

        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            object res = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

            foreach (var entry in bindingContext.ModelState)
            {
                if (entry.Value.Errors != null)
                {
                    var itemsToReplace = new List<ModelError>();
                    foreach (var err in entry.Value.Errors)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(err.ErrorMessage) && err.Exception != null)
                        {
                            var ex = err.Exception;
                            while (!(ex is FormatException) && ex != null)
                                ex = ex.InnerException;
                            if (ex != null)
                            {
                                itemsToReplace.Add(err);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var err in itemsToReplace)
                    {
                        var ex = err.Exception;
                        entry.Value.Errors.Remove(err);

                        entry.Value.Errors.Add(GetErrorMessageForType(bindingContext.ModelType));
                    }
                }

            }

            return res;
        }

    }
```